# Making dates go back passed 2011 DateTime Generator on Ruby on Rails Scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I am making a new site and I cannot get dates in a generated scaffold to go back passed 2011.  The months , days, and time work perfectly.  However, I cannot moved the year past back 2001.  I am making an Astrology Porn site with a database of compatible female pornstars with  an inputted zodiac sign.  I hope you can help me fix the date issues I am trying to add Kianna Dior to the zodiac sign and she was born in 1969, so it will not work with rails 5 default generator for any dateTime columns that are generated via scaffold.

Comment: ... not sure if serious... However, if you are serious, please include some sample code. I assume you're using a `date_select` control, but seeing the actual code would allow for something better than speculation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the date input options:

`date_select :date, :start_year => Date.current.year, :end_year => 1920`

[date_select api documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select)

Answer (score 0):

This worked in _form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :datez %>
    <%= f.date_select :datez, :start_year => Date.current.year, :end_year => 1920 %>
  </div>
```

Thanks for the input